# Is there any way to make rake display the source code of a task from the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

One can make rake display all available tasks with `rake -T` or `rake --tasks`.  But is it possible to either trace those tasks to their source without grepping around or better still, to make rake display the task source for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was typing this, I noticed that `rake --help` gives two options with identical descriptions:

```
-D, --describe [PATTERN]         Describe the tasks (matching optional PATTERN), then exit.
-W, --where [PATTERN]            Describe the tasks (matching optional PATTERN), then exit.
```

It turns out that `rake -W <task>` does output the location of the task source, although it sort of looks like it is culled from a stack trace.

This answers the first question.  Does anyone know if it's possible to print the task source directly from the command line?